# Screensaver Child Process Outlives Screensaver

Tags: process, windows-7, blocking, screensaver

I have this situation. I have a custom screensaver that starts another process using `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("MyHelperApp.exe")`. That second process lives on after the screensaver itself is closed and disposed.

The problem is that the screensaver only gets displayed once. Unless I do one of two things:

- Go to Task Manager and kill `"MyHelperApp.exe"`. This will allow the screensaver to run one more time, then I have to repeat this step.
- Comment out `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("MyHelperApp.exe")`. Now the screensaver runs normally, as you would expect.

If I test the screensaver by right-clicking and selecting *'Test'*, I do not get these problems. I can test it as many times as I want. It is only when Windows manages the installed screensaver that I see this problem.

It is not a blocking problem, because I have screensaver write to a file before getting to `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("MyHelperApp.exe")`, and the file never gets written, so the screensaver is not called a second time.

Windows 7 desktop.

Comment: The system runs screen savers in a job object. Screen savers are not supposed to create child processes that outlive them. That is a security vulnerability (repudiation).

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks. That's really good to know.